# ruby on rails Mysql installation problem on ubuntu

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, rubygems

Ubuntu 10.10

Everything worked fine untill  i tried to install a plugin, something went very wrong with mysql2. I tried te remove and reinstall it with this result:

```
gem install mysql2
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing mysql2:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /home/ruben/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/home/ruben/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/bin/ruby
/home/ruben/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:368:in `try_do': The complier failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
    from /home/ruben/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:435:in `try_link0'
    from /home/ruben/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:440:in `try_link'
    from /home/ruben/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:552:in `try_func'
    from /home/ruben/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:797:in `block in have_func'
    from /home/ruben/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:693:in `block in checking_for'
    from /home/ruben/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:280:in `block (2 levels) in postpone'
    from /home/ruben/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:254:in `open'
    from /home/ruben/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:280:in `block in postpone'
    from /home/ruben/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:254:in `open'
    from /home/ruben/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:276:in `postpone'
    from /home/ruben/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:692:in `checking_for'
    from /home/ruben/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:796:in `have_func'
    from extconf.rb:9:in `<main>'


Gem files will remain installed in /home/ruben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/mysql2-0.2.6 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/ruben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/mysql2-0.2.6/ext/mysql2/gem_make.out
```

Hope someone can help! Do not have the time to reinstall my whole server!

Comment: What in the `mkmf.log` file looks like the error? While you're reading the log file for the error, start running `sudo apt-get install build-essential` in another terminal. That alone might fix the problem, but I'm guessing it will only help move along the problem to another newer problem. :)

Comment: sudo apt-get install... did not much everything was up to date This was in the mkmf.log (see answer)

Answer (score 1):

```
foradian@foradian-1:~$ cd blog
foradian@foradian-1:~/blog$ rake db:create
(in /home/foradian/blog)
rake aborted!
syntax error on line 9, col 2: `  socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'

(See full trace by running task with --trace)
foradian@foradian-1:~/blog$
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to install the mysql client header package like this :

```
sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
```

You need package *build-essential* (suggested by sarnold in comments).

more informations here : http://rubydoc.info/gems/mysql2/0.3.13/frames

Answer (score 0):

mkmf.log ==>

```
"gcc -o conftest -I/home/ruben/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/include/ruby-1.9.1/i686-linux -I/home/ruben/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -I/home/ruben/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I.  -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64   -O3 -ggdb -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-long-long  -fPIC conftest.c  -L. -L/home/ruben/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib -Wl,-R/home/ruben/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib -L.  -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic     -Wl,-R -Wl,/home/ruben/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib -L/home/ruben/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib -lruby-static  -lpthread -lrt -ldl -lcrypt -lm   -lc"
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2:
3: int main() {return 0;}
/* end */
```