# MySQL Ruby Gem install issues

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, macos, osx-server

So I know that this question has been asked before, and I have looked through all of the previous answers and still can't find a solution.  Hoping you all can help.

The setup: I am running Mac OS X 10.6 Server.  I have used the built in MySQL install on web apps and it works great.  Now I am trying to run a RoR app that requires MySQL.

So, whenever I enter

```
gem install mysql
```

it spits back the following error:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing mysql:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/Users/admin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/ruby extconf.rb --with-mysql-config=/var/mysql
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/admin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/ruby
    --with-mysql-config
extconf.rb:35:in ``': Permission denied - /var/mysql --cflags (Errno::EACCES)
    from extconf.rb:35:in `<main>'


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3/gems/mysql-2.8.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3/gems/mysql-    2.8.1/ext/mysql_api/gem_make.out
```

So, through my research, I tried to specifically state the location of the MySQL install.

```
gem install mysql -- --with-mysql-config=/var/mysql
```

Unfortunately, with the same results.

Any ideas of where to go from here?

Thanks!

Kevin

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't using mysql2?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167598/mysql-install-error-failed-to-build-gem-native-extension

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/354194/mysql-installation-troubles

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5219256/ruby-on-rails-mysql-installation-problem-on-ubuntu

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4613116/difficulties-installing-mysql-gem-on-ubuntu

Comment: This is one of the most popular question on SO

Comment: hey all...sorry, but none of the things you all suggested worked. However, I was able to find the answer, posted here for the next one who comes looking for the answer - worked like a charm!

[Installing MySQL Ruby Gem on Snow Leopard Server](http://www.icoretech.org/2009/11/installing-mysql-ruby-gem-in-snow-leopard-server/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Kevin,

This article may help you address your problem:

http://rapd.wordpress.com/2007/05/17/battle-against-ror-gem-install-mysql/

Comment: Awesome.  Posted article did the trick for me.  This line in particular from the article: `sudo gem install mysql -- --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config`

Answer (score 1):

On Mac OSX Lion 10.7 this command helped me install the mysql2 gem:

```
sudo gem install mysql2 -- --with-mysql-lib=/usr/local/Cellar/mysql55/5.5.30/lib --with-mysql-include=/usr/local/Cellar/mysql55/5.5.30/include/
```

Before this I did install mysql55 via brew like described above.

Answer (score 0):

Your milage may vary, but here's what seemed to work for us. First, ensure you have the right libraries on there *first* (from Apple):

http://www.opensource.apple.com/other/MySQL-53.binaries.tar.gz

Install those via:

```
sudo tar -xvf ~/Downloads/MySQL-53.binaries.tar -C /
```

Then, for our 10.6 Server, the location of mysql_config was different:

```
gem install mysql -- --with-mysql-config=/usr/bin/mysql_config
```

Comment: I installed mysql using homebrew and i am getting "Permission Denied" error. `gem install mysql -- --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/bin/mysql_config 
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
    Permission denied - /Users/pratikkhadloya/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/mysql-2.8.1/COPYING`

Comment: Looks like, my previous gem install of mysql was done using sudo, so i uninstalled it and then reinstalled and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
gem install mysql2 -- '--with-mysql-lib="c:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\lib" --with-mysql-include="c:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\include"'
```

Using the above worked with ruby Ruby 2.0 on Windows. I changed the library to just `lib` instead of `lib\opt` because `lib\opt` is not present in MySQL Server 5.5.

I picked the above command from a solution to this problem presented at:
http://rorguide.blogspot.com/2011/03/installing-mysql2-gem-on-ruby-192-and.html

Answer (score 0):

I had success with this sudo gem install `mysql -v '2.8.1' -- --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config`
but specifying the mysql version that I need